# Independent process in php

Tags: php, process

I will converting a pdf to images using imagick and php, When the user upload the pdf file with ajax is sending and catching by a php process wich convert the pdf to images, the problem is sometimes this process take a lot of time and expire the execution of the php script.

Can I return the finish of the ajax execute and the server continues with images render in the server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You'd decouple the conversion from the Ajax return, and process the file independently.  A few typical scenarios:

1. A "cron job" does the conversions.
2. You fork a process (pcntl_fork(), or perhaps pthreads) to handle the
       responsibility.
3. You might even manage a system call with backgrounding (in 'Nix,
       look up "Unix Job Control").

Comment: Would not recommend cron though as the trigger is a set time, in OP's case he is better of to use the upload as trigger to start the other process

Comment: Probably so.  It's really situation-specific to a degree.  If there are enough files to do it on a regular basis, a frequent cronjob might not be a Bad Thing(tm).  One of the big drivers would probably be whether or not there's a need for timely end-user feedback.